# Align a figure caption lines

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, captions

I have an image with caption in LaTeX:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,height=0.8\textheight,keepaspectratio]{img/image9}
   \caption{Text text text text text text\\*
   On the basis of: \cite{Smi00}}
\label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}
```

it looks like that:

```
|                                                           |
|___________________________________________________________|
          Figure 3.3 Text text text text text text
                   On the basis of: [4]

...
```

I'd like to align both lines of caption, but keep the centering of the whole caption, i.e. to change it to something like that:

```
|                                                           |
|___________________________________________________________|
          Figure 3.3 Text text text text text text
          On the basis of: [4]

...
```

Not:

```
|                                                           |
|___________________________________________________________|
Figure  3.3    Text    text    text     text    text     text
On the basis of: [4]

...
```

Or:

```
|                                                           |
|___________________________________________________________|
          Figure 3.3 Text text text text text text
On the basis of: [4]

...
```

...but all my attempts failed.

Does anybody know how it can be done?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It is usually quite helpful to add a complete working code example, as document classes, loaded packages etc. can influence the problem and its solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package [`varwidth`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) provides environment `varwidth` that is a `minipage`, but the width is reduced, if the lines are shorter.
The caption text can be formatted with environment `varwidth` by an own caption format that can be defined with package [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{varwidth}{%
  \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}#1#2#3\end{varwidth}%
}
\captionsetup{format=varwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \rule{.8\linewidth}{1ex}% simulating \includegraphics
  \caption{Text text text text text text\\*
    On the basis of [1]}
 \label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- For the caption entry in the list of figures you can use the optional argument of `\caption` to provide a (shorter) version without an explicit line break.

Comment: Looks pretty handy!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to attain this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\figwidth{15pc}% Adjust the caption width here
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
 \vskip\abovecaptionskip
 \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
 \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\figwidth
   \mbox{}\hfill\parbox{\figwidth}{%
   #1: #2\par}\hfill\mbox{}%
 \else
   \global \@minipagefalse
   \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
 \fi
 \vskip\belowcaptionskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
  \fbox{\hbox to 20pc{\vbox to 5pc{\mbox{}}}}
  \caption{Text text text text text text
  On the basis of: }
\label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Please set the width of the caption as required by adjusting the macro `\figwidth`.